# golang consume rest api pagination

Tags: go, pagination

I am trying to write simple http request to get data from Zendesk API. The simple request works, but I am not able to find out any example to handle pagination. Unfortunatelly, I was not able able find any example on the net related to consuming REST API with pagination.

I am new to Go and I am not professional programmer. I have the code working in Python where I use while loop with NextPage variable. But I am trying to learn Go and trying to rewrite it.

Please can you give me an advise? Should I do it in the same way using a loop with NextPage and appending json data, or is there any other way?

Please assume I am learning. Thank you.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type Response struct {
    Organizations []struct {
        URL                string        `json:"url"`
        ID                 int64         `json:"id"`
        Name               string        `json:"name"`
        SharedTickets      bool          `json:"shared_tickets"`
        SharedComments     bool          `json:"shared_comments"`
        ExternalID         interface{}   `json:"external_id"`
        CreatedAt          time.Time     `json:"created_at"`
        UpdatedAt          time.Time     `json:"updated_at"`
        DomainNames        []string      `json:"domain_names"`
        Details            interface{}   `json:"details"`
        Notes              interface{}   `json:"notes"`
        GroupID            interface{}   `json:"group_id"`
        Tags               []interface{} `json:"tags"`
        OrganizationFields struct {
            SevenX24HourSupportPurchased interface{} `json:"7x24_hour_support_purchased_"`
            K8SNodesLicensed             interface{} `json:"k8s_nodes_licensed"`
            LatestClosedOpportunityDate  interface{} `json:"latest_closed_opportunity_date"`
            PartnerOfRecordInSf          string      `json:"partner_of_record_in_sf"`
            VcpusLicensed                interface{} `json:"vcpus_licensed"`
        } `json:"organization_fields"`
    } `json:"organizations"`
    NextPage     string      `json:"next_page"`
    PreviousPage interface{} `json:"previous_page"`
    Count        int         `json:"count"`
}

func organizationsGet() {
    url := "https://zendesk.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations.json"

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Basic blabla")

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    fmt.Println(res)
    fmt.Println(string(body))

    var responseObject Response
    json.Unmarshal(body, &responseObject)


    for i := 0; i < len(responseObject.Organizations); i++ {
        fmt.Println(responseObject.Organizations[i].Name + "  " + strconv.FormatInt(int64(responseObject.Organizations[i].ID), 10))
        // fmt.Printf("%v,%v\n", responseObject.User[i].Name, responseObject.User[i].Email)
    }

}
```

Comment: You could try to make your function recursive. In most REST implementations the "NextPage" url is in the body somewhere. As long as it is you could continue to make calls and add the results to a common resultset.

Comment: Okay. I will try a FOR loop with appending json data as explained here https://dev.to/evilcel3ri/append-data-to-json-in-go-5gbj

Comment: I read manuals for the recursive function and I see what you mean. I will try to code it and come back with end result. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Good, let us know if it works, then you can turn it into an answer for future generations that have the same question.